# Anyway for my c++ application to communicate with GDB?

Tags: c++, gdb, coredump, gdbserver

I would like read a core-dump file dumped with gcore. 
However, I would like to read a coredump file in my c++ application, not with gdb terminal command. 
For instance, I have a executable program 'testEx' and it is killed by some reason then 'testEx' left a core dump. 
I am creating a C++ application 'readGDB' to analyze core dump created by 'testEx'. 
Any c++ library and example to read a core file?

Comment: Core files are just executable files (a.out or ELF or whatever it is on Mac OS X). So any library that reads executable formats will do.

Comment: @n.m. If you wish to execute 'dump binary memory' command with gdb on given coredump, how would you do it in c++?

Comment: I would read the memory with libelf or similar, then write it to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any c++ library and example to read a core file?

Reading the `core` is trivial: you just `open` and `read` it.

What's not trivial is understanding what the contents means. A `core` file is an `ELF` file, so it has a lot of internal structure, and libraries such as `libelf` can help you read specific sections of the `core`.

But that's still *long* way away from what GDB does: to *really* understand the contents, you also need to implement symbol management, stack unwinding, and many more things. In short, you will have to re-implement half of GDB.

So why not just use GDB? You can talk to GDB from your application, and make it give you the answers you are seeking. GDB has a special [machine interface mode](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html) for just that purpose.